# How to repeat working code for multiple pages?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to crawl through many pages, I know it's pretty easy to do but I'am new to python.

My code works for a single page and it goes into the next page and I just need to somehow repeat the process again until last page.

```
driver.get("www.example.com")
titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.name")
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4000)")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Next Page")]').click()
```

The website contains 65 pages, I want to get titles from all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You might try with a while loop. While the "next-page" button is present do this:

```
driver.get("www.example.com")
titles = []
while (len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Next Page")]'))>0)
    titles.append(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.name"))
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4000)")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Next Page")]').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(('some-element')))
```

I added a wait condition after clicking the next page. The 'some-element' part signifies an element that is visible that signals to the user the page is ready to be used. You can change that as you see fit.

Comment: Tried this code but it only opens the website and after few seconds closes it :/

Comment: No it finishes, but only opens the website and that's all. I think loop should start with finding titles then scrolling down and pressing next page and so on. I hope it make sense

Comment: Add `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Next Page")]'))))` and `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Next Page")]'))))` after `driver.get()` and report what do you get printed.

Comment: Now it opens the website and gives error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'. I wrote full code, maybe I misunderstood something, you can look at it as an answer.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the "div.name"'

Comment: I changed it. Original is <span class="name">Text</span>

Comment: So change "div.name" to "span.name".

Comment: I already changed :) maybe I combined something wrong with yours and mine code :/